# How to specify common error page excluding 404 and 500 in web.xml

Tags: java, error-handling, web.xml

I already have two web pages designed for 404 and 500 error pages in web.xml

```
 <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/error/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/error/500.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

I want to redirect to a predesignated page for all the other errors.

Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be sufficient, along with few customer error related pages, you can add default page. So all error other than **404**, **500** , will be redirected to generic page `error.html`

```
<error-page>
    <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

or more customized, using **Exception** class, can be your custom exception class as well.

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
  <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

So code becomes,

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/error/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/error/500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following to tackle 400 and 500 `status error` codes.

Add the below lines in `web.xml` files

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/error/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/error/500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

In addition to above, you can also use the `Exception` type: See below:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/error/exception.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

The difference is: `<error-code>` and `<exception-type>` depends on which is used.